# Why its showing error in jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobiles 1.4.2
When i click one a link it takes to other  page its not displaying any content in that page,In console it showing this error

TypeError: a.widget.extend is not a function

When i comment link to javascript i.e http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js
Its displaying the content in that page

Please help me why its showing this error?

Comment: Change your script for using the non minified versions. Also some code you are using would be helpfull.

Comment: i didnot get,How to change this to non modified version

Comment: I tried using 1.4.1 version but its not working

Comment: please any one help me i am trying it since from yesterday

Comment: Try uising this (notminified version) http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js  instead... then you will exactly know where the error is.

Comment: I tried using (nonminified version) now its showing TypeError: $.widget.extend is not a function>I am nt getting what to do if any one know about this please help me

Comment: And can you post some of your code so we will see more.
As for now i also think you havent included the main jQuery library.

Comment: the code which i have added in header is<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  Its shoeing error only in that page and i am using same in all other pages those all working fine